# Mixing Razor Views and Web Forms Master Pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webforms, razor, master-pages

I'm attempting to do what Scott Hanselman describes below:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingRazorViewsAndWebFormsMasterPagesWithASPNETMVC3.aspx

I have a Web Form user control with code behind that is called from the Web Form and Razor Master Pages that is not working in the Razor layout:

```
<div id="navtop">
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("~/Controls/MasterPageMenu.ascx"); }
</div>
```

The user control contains the following:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MasterPageMenu.ascx.cs" Inherits="Controls.MasterPageMenu" %>
```

I get the error:
The view at '~/Controls/MasterPageMenu.ascx' must derive from ViewPage, ViewPage, ViewUserControl, or ViewUserControl.

What have I missed in getting this to work in the Razor view world?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work, just make sure that your partial derives from ViewUserControl:

```
<%@ Control 
    Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" 
%>
```

Remember that using server side controls in ASP.NET MVC is not something that's recommended even with the WebForms view engine and not something that you should even be attempting to do. In ASP.NET MVC you have layouts (master pages if you use WebForms view engine), views and partials. That's all. User controls belong to classic WebForms, not to ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: If I do the above I lose the ability to run the code behind in the user control that dynamically creates the menu.  Do I have to move that code to run in the aspx file of the user control?           Agree with your comments - this is a bridge solution for an entire website already built using WebForms view engine.

Comment: @RSchmit, why are you talking about code behind in an ASP.NET MVC application? Such things no longer exist. Forget about them. If you have some existing code, while waiting to migrate to MVC keep it, keep those WebForms the way they are and migrate them progressively. But absolutely never attempt to pollute an ASP.NET MVC application with such things. That's condemned to failure.

Comment: Agree with you - this a Brownfield application and I'm attempting to do new enhancements using the Razor view engine. There is plenty of pollution!  I'm still confused with the solution suggested by Scott Hanselman as he says you can reference the WebForm user controls from the Razor Layout.  Is it the only case that user control has no code behind then?  The existing code behind on this user control dynamically creates the menu for the website via the Menu server control.  I guess I could move the code behind to the aspx file and dynamically create the menu there?

Comment: @RSchmitt, oh no, you have mistaken something. By user controls he means partials. Probably the wrong word. Anyway, this works only if your ascx derives from ViewUserControl. And you should not be moving any code behind to the view. That would worsen things. In ASP.NET MVC what you call *code behind* belongs to controllers and models.